# Qt Designer from PySide6 and pyuic6 creates py file with wrong argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt-designer, pyside2, pyside6

I've made the UI in Qt Designer from PySide6 package. After calling `pyuic6 -o main_window.py -x MainWindow.ui` i have this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mikha\Desktop\Mika\Projects\log_viewer\main.py", line 20, in <module>
    window = MainWindow()
  File "C:\Users\mikha\Desktop\Mika\Projects\log_viewer\main.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\Desktop\Mika\Projects\log_viewer\main_window.py", line 16, in setupUi
    MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 500))
TypeError: 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget.setMinimumSize' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget.setMinimumSize(QSize)
Supported signatures:
  PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget.setMinimumSize(PySide6.QtCore.QSize)
  PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget.setMinimumSize(int, int)
```

I've already created the same files in previous projects and arguments in `setMinimumSize` was the same (`QSize(int, int)`). All worked. But it does not on my work laptop. (In addition, i've installed QtCreator, so, may be they have some conflicts ?)

Comment: `pyuic` is a PyQt tool - you can't use it with PySide. See the PySide6 Docs: [Using .ui files from Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/tutorials/basictutorial/uifiles.html).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the type check is not allowing a `QSize` instead of a `PySide6.QtCore.QSize`

Replace your L16

```
MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 500))
```

by

```
MainWindow.setMinimumSize(800, 500)
```

Comment: I've tried it, but than a lot of another errors appeared, at the continuation of the file. But i've found the solution. Look like it's better to use `pyside6-uic MainWindow.ui -o main_window.py` instead of default `pyuic6`

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally i've found the solution from this [source](https://geekscoders.com/how-to-use-designer-in-python-pyside6/).
So, instead of using `pyuic6` i've used `pyside6-uic MainWindow.ui -o main_window.py`.